# Shopify API error when add new product

Tags: php, api, shopify

I'm using Shopify API  with PHP CURL POST Method to create a product. Kindly find the following code and the response. I got error "Not Found".

```
    <?php

      $products_array = array(
      "product"=>array(
      'title'=>'',
      "title"=> "Burton Custom Freestlye 151",
      "body_html"=> "<strong>Good snowboard!</strong>",
      "vendor"=> "Burton",
      "product_type"=> "Snowboard",
      "published"=> false ,
      "variants"=>array(
                    array(
                    "sku"=>"t_009",
                    "price"=>20.00,
                    "grams"=>200,
                    "taxable"=>false,
                    )
                 )
       )
      );
      echo json_encode($products_array);
      echo "<br />";
      $url = "https://apikey:password@hostname/admin/products.json";

      $curl = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:   application/json; charset=utf-8'));
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($products_array));
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
      $response = curl_exec ($curl);
      curl_close ($curl);
      echo "<pre>";
      print_r($response); 


       ?>
```

The response of the request :

```
      {"product":{"title":"Burton Custom Freestlye 151","body_html":"Good snowboard!<\/strong>","vendor":"Burton","product_type":"Snowboard","published":false,"variants":[{"sku":"t_009","price":20,"grams":200,"taxable":false}]}}

       HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
       Server: nginx
       Date: Sat, 01 Apr 2017 21:08:04 GMT
       Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
       Transfer-Encoding: chunked
       Connection: keep-alive
       Vary: Accept-Encoding
       Vary: Accept-Encoding
       Vary: Accept-Encoding
       X-Frame-Options: DENY
       X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
       X-Download-Options: noopen
       X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: none
       X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block; report=/xss-     report?source%5Baction%5D=create&source%5Bapp%5D=Shopify&    source%5Bcontroller%5D=admin%2Fproducts&source%5Bsection%5D=admin&source%5Buuid%5D=5539f94e-776f-4672-ab2a-f340c0cf2ad1
       X-Dc: ash,chi2
       X-Request-ID: 5539f94e-776f-4672-ab2a-f340c0cf2ad1

       {"errors":"Not Found"}
```

How can I fix that error ? and what does that mean ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double check that you are using the right `.myshopify.com` hostname for your store. You can see this (along with the API key and password) after creating a private app in the Shopify admin: https://shopify.com/admin/apps/private